# On questions about the integral of the logarithm of the Riemann zeta function II

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, riemann-zeta, constants

With the help of [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) I know good approximations of the real part of the integral $$\int_0^1 \log \left(\zeta(x)\right)dx,$$
where $\zeta(x)$ denotes the Riemann zeta function (evaluated over real numbers).

See it as `int log(zeta(x))dx, from x=0 to 1` or `15 digits of int log(zeta(x))dx, from x=0 to 1`

> **Question.** I'm curious to know if this constant $$\Re\int_0^1 \log \left(\zeta(x)\right)dx$$ is in the literature. Can you provide me the reference? Then answer this question as a reference request adding what is the article showing/defining the value of this real constant, and I am going to search and read such statement. **Many thanks.**

My problem here is that I can not find the numeric value of this constant in 
The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences or in Internet.

Comment: Due that the Riemann zeta function is a special function involved in open problems, I don't know what facts are feasible to justify about the definition of previous constant. Thus I am asking the reference request, because I don't know how is defined from the analytic continuation of the zeta function.

Comment: Please show your attempts. Do you know any representation for $\log\zeta(s)$ in the strip $0<\text{Re}(s)<1$? Did you get something meaningful by exploiting the reflection formula for the $\zeta$ function?

Comment: It is not difficult to show that $\zeta(s)$ is real and negative for $s\in(0,1)$, hence you are actually looking for $$\int_{0}^{1}\log(-\zeta(s))\,ds.$$

Comment: Many thanks @JackD'Aurizio I didn't any attempt. I feel that calculate an approximation is difficult to me. There is an ocean of formulas about representations for the Riemann zeta in the mentioned strip.

Comment: Not really. Not as an infinite product, for instance (that would make tackling RH fairly easy). An there is a single reflection formula.

Comment: I've calculated the approximation with the help of WA, and I tried to find such approximation in Internet and being suspect that it isn't, then I think that it is very difficult to get @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{1}\log(-\zeta(s))\,ds \approx 0.674892868689. $$ Not by chance, this is close to $\log 2$.

Comment: When I take the logarithm of the Hadamard product I get several terms, some I know how get their integration, but for others like as $$\sum_{\rho}\log\left(1-\frac{s}{\rho}\right)$$ I'm unsure to get the integration term by term @JackD'Aurizio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to evaluate the integral in term of series over non-trivial zeros of $\zeta\left(s\right)$. [From the product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Hadamard_product) $$\zeta(s)=\pi^{\frac{s}{2}}\frac{\prod_{\rho}\left(1-\frac{s}{\rho}\right)}{2(s-1)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{s}{2}\right)}$$ where $\rho$ runs over the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta\left(s\right),$ we get $$\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(-\zeta\left(s\right)\right)ds=\log\left(\pi\right)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{s}{2}ds-\log\left(2\right)-\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(1-s\right)ds$$ $$-\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\Gamma\left(1+\frac{s}{2}\right)\right)ds+\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{\rho}\log\left(1-\frac{s}{\rho}\right)ds.$$Obviously $$\log\left(\pi\right)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{s}{2}ds-\log\left(2\right)-\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(1-s\right)ds=\frac{\log\left(\pi\right)}{4}-\log\left(2\right)-1$$ and $$\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\Gamma\left(1+\frac{s}{2}\right)\right)ds=2\int_{0}^{1/2}\log\left(\Gamma\left(1+x\right)\right)dx$$ $$=3\log\left(A\right)-1-\frac{7}{12}\log\left(2\right)+\frac{\log\left(\pi\right)}{2}$$ where $A$ is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html). So, by the Taylor series for the logarithm we have $$\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{\rho}\log\left(1-\frac{s}{\rho}\right)ds=-\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{\rho}\sum_{k\geq1}\left(\frac{s}{\rho}\right)^{k}\frac{1}{k}ds$$ $$=-\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{2\rho}-\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{\rho}\sum_{k\geq2}\left(\frac{s}{\rho}\right)^{k}\frac{1}{k}ds.$$ Note that $\sum_{\rho}1/\rho$ is convergent assuming that the pair of zeros $\rho$ and $1-\rho$ are combinated. Now since $$\sum_{\rho}\int_{0}^{1}\left|\sum_{k\geq2}\left(\frac{s}{\rho}\right)^{k}\frac{1}{k}\right|ds\leq\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{\left|\rho\right|^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}-\log\left(1-s\right)ds<\infty$$ and $$\sum_{\rho}\sum_{k\geq2}\frac{1}{\left|\rho\right|^{k}k}\int_{0}^{1}s^{k}ds\leq\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{\left|\rho\right|^{2}}\sum_{k\geq2}\frac{1}{k\left(k+1\right)}<\infty$$ we can exchange the integral with the double series and so $$\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{\rho}\log\left(1-\frac{s}{\rho}\right)ds=-\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{2\rho}-\sum_{\rho}\sum_{k\geq2}\frac{1}{\rho^{k}k}\int_{0}^{1}s^{k}ds$$ $$=-\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{2\rho}-\sum_{\rho}\sum_{k\geq2}\frac{1}{\rho^{k}k\left(k+1\right)}$$ $$=-\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{2\rho}-\sum_{\rho}\left(\log\left(1-\frac{1}{\rho}\right)\left(\rho-1\right)+1-\frac{1}{2\rho}\right)$$ then, [since](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91280/is-this-sum-of-reciprocals-of-zeta-zeros-correct/91299#91299) $\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{\rho}=\frac{\gamma}{2}+1-\frac{\log(4\pi)}{2},$ we get

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(-\zeta\left(s\right)\right)ds=-\frac{5}{2}-\frac{\gamma}{4}-\frac{13\log\left(2\right)}{12}+3\log\left(A\right)+\log\left(\pi\right)$$ $$-\sum_{\rho}\left(\log\left(1-\frac{1}{\rho}\right)\left(\rho-1\right)+1-\frac{1}{2\rho}\right).$$

Comment: Wow, many thanks I am going to study it this week. Many thanks to you and Jack, you and he are incredible.